# How do you get rid unwanted squares when rendering on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

So  I was using Adobe Photoshop CC to make a 3D text and when I rendered it I got these small little squares. How Do I get rid of the sqaures

Comment: I never had this problem, might be specific to your file / object / computer

Comment: Before you rendered the type,there may have been "non-printing" marks in the layer such as crop marks, bounding box vertices, etc. Try to clean up any apparent blank space before rendering.

Comment: Are you using a trial version of a plugin? They sometimes add these squares to prevent you from using the plugin without buying it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not crazy I get the squares on every render. I have no fix but setting the tile size to huge reduces the total number of squares.

Comment: And you are not using a trial version of a paid plugin? (as I've also asked the OP)